# Recent automatic update of Samba in 20.04 results in 'Fail to retreive share list from server' when trying to access windows machines on LAN

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing

I am running an ethernet LAN with Windows XP through Windows 10 machines interfacing with all 6 general flavors of Ubuntu. Since 20.04 has SMB1 deactivated, was able to get complete readability of share files both ways by adding `client min protocol = NT1` and `server min protocol = NT1` to the global section of smb.conf on each Ubuntu machine. This was with relevant Samba files version [2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.1] loaded. These files were all recently updated to 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2, and while Windows still sees Ubuntu shares, all the respective Ubuntu machines return the title message above, adding that there is `No such file or directory`, when trying to access Windows shares. (They can still access Ubuntu shares.) The smb.conf is unchanged, so what is missing or needs to be changed in the updated version (For the time being I have forced the previous version with Synaptic.)

Comment: Looks like a bug in the samba update from Ubuntu, this worked for me:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=371366&start=40

Answer (score 0):

The initial fix as discussed in 'forums.linuxmint.com/' is essentially what I did to restore complete LAN interfunctionality, that is, removing the relevant samba [2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2] files and their dependencies, and force installing the previous [2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.1] versions with their dependencies, using synaptic package manager. I also found that the single terminal entry 'sudo apt-mark hold samba' is sufficient to hold back updates on all relevant samba-related files, at least on all my machines. All versions of Windows I have can still read either of the samba versions without problems, regardless.
I can also still access all the Windows shares simply with smb://(ip.address) in the 'connect to server' box in 'other locations'.
I am wondering, though, what happened that the [.2] samba update does not even recognize that Windows shares exist, or so it seems. (Ubuntu shares still work fine, in all 8 Ubuntu versions I have)